# DD-WRT Flashing

Tags: router

I am looking to see if anyone here has come up with a method for flashing several linksys WRT54GL routers at the same time with DD-WRT? 
I think this would be possible with a switch and a tftp script ?

Any thoughts on how to get past the hard boot process when flashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the flash from each board, and flash them in a gang programmer.  The default IP address that you use while flashing is the same for each of them, so parallel TFTPing is out of the question.